# Do bounties *work* on some Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Do bounties *work* on some Stack Exchange sites? They definitely [don't work on Photo-SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/why-dont-bounties-ever-work-on-this-site/1693#1693). I'm curious if this is true network-wide.

I see that Stack Overflow has an astounding-to-me 250+ bounty questions open right now. That might be a different problem than what we're having! The other big sites like Superuser and Serverfault also only have a few. Is the huge number of bounty questions a problem at SO?

Do other *smaller* SE sites see bounties as working out? Is it something unique to Photo-SE? Is there something localized we could improve, or something we could do across the network?

Would it be possible to balance something for both the handful of featured questions that most sites might have *and* the torrent one sees on Stack Overflow? Recent tweaks like sorting by the amount of rep offered seem focused at the too-many-bounties problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from here: [Original Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing)
And here: [Current Stats](http://api.photo.stackexchange.com/1.0/stats)

There are not ***that***  many visitors and questions on the site.

Also being that there are only **13**(thirteen) unanswered questions on the site

Therefore bounties might not work as much.
But it does put your question in the featured tab, which might boost it somewhat.

Comment: Those statistics are from over a year ago. I'm aware that the questions get put in the featured tab. The fact is that on Photo-SE this doesn't attract good, new answers. I'm wondering if that's a specific or a network-wide problem. (Or, network wide except Stack Overflow, which seems to be a special case.)

Comment: @mattdm I added the current stats

Comment: So, are you saying that "they don't work because it's a small site and bounties work fine and attract good answers on larger sites"?

Comment: @mattdm basically.

Comment: _Do_ they work on larger sites other that Stack Overflow? I see from your profile that you're basically only active on that site.

Comment: @mattdm they seem to work. (and I am active on others, just not as high rep ;-))

Comment: @mattdm - Bounties doesn't work when nobody knows the answer. On smaller sites that's more probable.